# Which Ruby memoize pattern does ActiveSupport::Memoizable refer to?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport, memoization

So in Rails 3.2, ActiveSupport::Memoizable has been deprecated.

The message reads:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and
will be removed in future releases,simply use Ruby memoization
pattern instead.
```

It refers to "Ruby memoization pattern" (singular) as if there's one pattern we should all know and refer to...

I presume they mean something like:

```
def my_method
  @my_method ||= # ... go get the value
end
```

or

```
def my_method
  return @my_method if defined?(@my_method)

  @my_method = # ... go get the value
end
```

Is there something else I've missed?

Comment: If you want 'false' or 'nil', it would not be saved using Ruby's memoizable. So if you want to implement your own memoizable wrapper, add a way to save 'false' and 'nil'.

Comment: As a side note (stumbling over this ancient question), I've proposed "rose memoization" as the name for this pattern: https://thepugautomatic.com/2016/01/rose-memoization/

Comment: @HenrikN I’ve stumbled upon your blog a few times. Nice to bump into you here

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Here is the commit (and subsequent discussion) where Memoizable was deprecated: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/36253916b0b788d6ded56669d37c96ed05c92c5c

The author advocates the `@foo ||= ...` approach and [points to this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/36253916b0b788d6ded56669d37c96ed05c92c5c#commitcomment-433227) as an example for migration: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f2c0fb32c0dce7f8da0ce446e2d2f0cba5fd44b3.

Edit:
Note that I don't necessarily interpret this change as meaning that all instances of `memoize` can or should be replaced w/ this pattern. I read it as meaning that Memoizable is no longer needed/wanted in the Rails code itself. As the comments point out, Memoizable is much more than just a wrapper around `@foo ||= ...`. If you need those features, go ahead and use Memoizable, you'll just have to get it from somewhere other than ActiveSupport (I'm guessing someone will fork a gem version, if they haven't already).

Answer (score 33):

Another option is to use the Memoist gem:

- [Memoist on GitHub](https://github.com/matthewrudy/memoist)
- [Memoist on RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/gems/memoist)

It is a direct extraction from `ActiveSupport::Memoizable` and can be used as a drop-in replacement. Just `require 'memoist'` and change

```
extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable
```

to

```
extend Memoist
```

Answer (score 2):

Just an addition to the top answer, to memoize a class method use the following pattern:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    def bar
      @bar ||= begin
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the comments on [the commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/36253916b0b788d6ded56669d37c96ed05c92c5c) [referenced above by avaynshtok](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9156249/578288), I’m going with this:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silence { extend ActiveSupport::Memoizable }
```

… because I figure I’ll know when `Memoizable` is ripped out of ActiveSupport from my RSpec suite dying right out of the starting gate.